# How to fix merge conflicts without a merge or rebase using --no-commit

Tags: git, merge, conflict

For better or worse I'm working with a setup that has master, release and develop branches. We branch off master and merge into develop. Branches that pass QA are then merged into a release branch, testing on staging, them merged into master.

When there's a conflict between a feature branch and develop we can't do a merge or rebase as that will get a bunch of stuff from develop into the feature branch that isn't ready to be deployed.

Is this a sensible process?

1. get latest develop branch
2. checkout feature branch
3. run `git merge --no-ff --no-commit develop`
4. fix conflicts
5. `git merge --continue`
6. when it finishes push the feature branch for a PR

Comment: short answer: yes

Comment: I don't fully undersand the process... however, I want to say something: `we can't do a merge or rebase as that will get a bunch of stuff from develop into the feature branch that isn't ready to be deployed`. That is not true about rebase. When rebasing a feature, you can do so discarding revisions you don't want very easily: `git rebase --onto new-base old-base feature-branch`. You can tell git what the old base was so that it doesn't pick those revisions when rebasing.

Comment: @eftshitf0 I'll have a go at that too, thanks.